# Mysql: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    comment_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    comment_text varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
    uploaded datetime NOT NULL,
    primary key(comment_id),
    constraint fk_user_comments foreign key(user_id) references user(user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    constraint fk_product_comments foreign key(product_id) references product(product_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;
```

and I'm trying to insert data into this table.

```
INSERT INTO comments(user_id,product_id,comment_text,uploaded) VALUES(1,'brbr',1,Now());
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `fk_product_comments` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

User with id 1 exists and product with id 1 exists so now i have no idea whats causing the problem.

Comment: You're not inserting a value for your primary key comment_id. That is wrong. Fix that first. And also can you share the structure & data from your product & user tables ? And product_id declared as int you're providing a string value, which is wrong. That's why your query fails.

Comment: Oh f... me. Now i feel like imbecile :D. Thanks.

Comment: @Venkat: _"You're not inserting a value for your primary key comment_id. That is wrong"_ Huh? It's an `auto_increment` field. The whole point is not to set it yourself.

Comment: Oops thanks for pointing that out. Agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your column list's order messed up.
You're attempting to insert a row with a `product_id` of `'brbr'` (which MySQL treats as 0) and a comment text of `1` (which MySQL converts as to `'1'`).

Reordering the the column list to match the values (or vise-versa) should solve it:

```
INSERT INTO comments
(user_id, product_id, comment_text, uploaded)                
VALUES (1, 1, 'brbr', NOW());
-- Here ---^
```

Answer (score 1):

This because you are not adding value according to your column sequence.

This is correct query.

```
INSERT INTO comments(user_id,product_id,comment_text,uploaded) VALUES(1,1,'brbr',Now())
```

Comment: Please explain your answers rather than just dumping code.

Comment: Sorry . I m new here. @Lightness Races in Otbit

Comment: "Member for 1 year, 2 months" :)

Comment: Yes, but I m active from last few month.

Comment: Okay so that's enough time to realise that answers should provide knowledge, insight and proof, rather than just "here's some code to run; trust me!" Anyway, it's better now. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today as I was dealing with Schema that wasn't designed by me. I added tables and relationships (FK) and things went KaBoom!

Upon investigation, I found the other buddy was using MyIsam Engine for that table and I was using InnoDB.

Changing the table from MyIsam to InnoDB ssolved the Issue!